# How to download ports OpenBSD

Tags: unix, ports, openbsd

How to extract the ports, src, sys trees to /user/ports, /usr/src, usr/src/sys in OpenBSD. Command to do the download and the untar.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [PortsFetch](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/ports/ports.html#PortsFetch) section of the faq:

> Once you have decided which flavor of the ports tree you want, you can get it from different sources. The table below gives an overview of where you can find the different flavors, and in which form. An 'o' marks availability and '-' means it is not available through that specific source.

Look for a file named ports.tar.gz on the mirrors.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ ftp https://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/$(uname -r)/{ports.tar.gz,SHA256.sig}
$ signify -Cp /etc/signify/openbsd-$(uname -r | cut -c 1,3)-base.pub -x SHA256.sig ports.tar.gz
```

You want to untar this file in the `/usr` directory, which will create `/usr/ports` and all the directories under it.

```
# cd /usr
# tar xzf /tmp/ports.tar.gz
```